# creating login page with compering data into sqlite3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I am trying to create login page in my application.  For that I am using sqlite database(journeymapper.db3 it is database name) which has UserInformation table 
For that use the fowling code:

```
 -(void)checkindatabase
{
NSString *direct = [[NSString alloc]init] ;
NSString *dbPath = [direct stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"journeymapper.db3"];


if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"open");
    NSString *sql = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select Username='%@',Password='%@' from UserInformation",txtuser.text,txtpass.text];
    //[sql UTF8String];
        //NSLog(@"'%s'",[sql UTF8String]);
    sqlite3_stmt *statment;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statment, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
         if(sqlite3_step(statment) == SQLITE_ROW)
         {

             UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                    message:@"Welcome to joureny" delegate:nil 
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alert show];
             [alert release];  
         }


    }


    sqlite3_finalize(statment);

}
sqlite3_close(database);
}

-(IBAction)login
{
    [self checkindatabase]; 
}
```

I am entering right user name & password but it doesn't show me the alertview how can I achieve this.  Please help me on how I can create the login page.

Comment: I think dbPath should contain full path of database not only name. try to debug you'r database open successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be 2 of ur assignment are incorrect.1. check dbpath and query

1.

```
    NSArray *dirPath =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDir =[dirPath objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath =[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbname.db"]];
```

2.

Change Your query as

```
NSString *sql = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select * from UserInformation where Username='%@' and Password='%@'",txtuser.text,txtpass.text];
```

if it return some thing ...Your username and password is correct .or else one of the text is in correct

**Edited Answer**

```
 //To check open DB or not   
 if(open DB)
   //ur code
 else
  NSLog(@"open fails & error is ::%s",sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));

 // To validate Password    

 if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
  {   if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            { 
         //user name is correct
         //if u want to print in log use below code  
         NSString *username=[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)       sqlite3_column_text(statement,0)];  
         NSString *password = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement,1)];

            }
       else    
         // Authentication failed
  }
```

Best Regards,

Comment: it's not working.  can please you send sample code to solve this?

Comment: Every thing is fine.in your code ,you tried to print **open** log value after your Sqlite DB(journeymapper.db3) opened successfully.whether it works

Comment: it DB succesfully open but when go on this condition if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,[sql UTF8String],-1,&statment,NULL) == SQLITE_OK) after going this it directly jumped out from the loop.it will not check     if(sqlite3_step(statment) == SQLITE_ROW)                               {
this condition where i have my UIAlertView //when user right username & password                                         }

Comment: it show me error :----------------------------------loginTest[19383:207] select * from UserInformation where UserName='(null)' and Password='(null)' 
2011-04-05 16:01:17.750 loginTest[19383:207] open

Comment: this means ur user enter value itself null.that is txtuser.text,txtpass.text return null. first check why the UItextfield value is null???

Comment: so only problem is your select query.which is incorrect because where condition element have null value.

Answer (score 0):

Use this I think this will be helpful for you.

```
databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"ApplicationData" ofType:@"db"];  
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &adddata) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"open");


    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=\"%@\" and password=\"%@\"",userNameText.text,passWordText.text];
    NSLog(@"%@",querySQL);

    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    int c=sqlite3_prepare_v2(adddata, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL); 
    NSLog(@"%d",c);
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(adddata, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {


            NewViewController *contacts=[[NewViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:nil];
            [self presentModalViewController:contacts animated:YES];
    }

    else 
        {
            alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"alert" message:@"Incorrect username & password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
            [alert show];  

            userNameText.text=@"";
            passWordText.text=@"";
        }
    }

    sqlite3_close(adddata);    
}
```

and in .h file you also use this

```
#import "/usr/include/sqlite3.h"
sqlite3 *adddata;
NSString *databasePath;
```